# Job is not running but it's listed and wont cancel

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My dataflow job failed, and now I can't cancel it although it still shows in list. Any ideas how to cancel this? It's been blocked (Status: Not started) for hours.

> Failed to cancel job [2018-06-08_10_54_30-17767897971415678082]: (912f110596c141c3): Workflow modification failed. Causes: (6b15c5f277fb4014): Operation cancel not allowed for job 20
>   18-06-08_10_54_30-17767897971415678082. Job is not yet ready for canceling. Please retry in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the account (Service Account) not having requisite access, correct scopes not being set, incorrect region IDs etc, the error above could also be because of passing incorrect project ID or job ID ...
the format of the request is https://content-dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/projectID/jobs/jobID?location=locationString&alt=json&key=someKey

So interchanging projectID for jobID and spaces in projectID/jobID etc are all going to lead to this error.
Please ensure that those basics are taken care of. I wasted 3 hours because I was sending my projectID for my jobID

Answer (score 0):

Either this was a temporary issue and it got resolved by retrying after some time (as suggested by the error message), or this looks like an issue that the Stack Overflow community will not be able to solve, so you should rather create a case with the GCP Support team (if you can do so) or instead [create an issue in Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers), under the Dataflow component, providing the necessary details for the Support team to investigate the issue.

Before doing that, you should make sure that:

1. Retrying the cancel operation after some time does not solve the issue (i.e. this is not a temporary issue).
2. Canceling the job does not work both from [the Dataflow UI](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/pipelines/stopping-a-pipeline) and [using the `gcloud beta dataflow jobs cancel` command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataflow/jobs/cancel).

Finally, once you are able to solve your issues with canceling the job you mentioned, you can share the final resolution as an answer to your own question, so that future visitors of this question know more about the issue you experienced and how to proceed with it.

Comment: in my case it was simply that I hadn't installed the dataflow api in my project. thanks for the suggestions though, i will try those next time, if any.

Comment: I am glad to hear that you could solve your issue. Feel free to post that as an answer (and [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), or [accept mine if you found it useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), for letting the community know that this issue is solved. And welcome to Stack Overflow!